# Simplifying a multitude of while loops inside a while loop for ifstream function

Tags: c++

```
while (getline(input, s)) {

 //These are lower case letters. 
 while (s.find("a") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("a"), 1, "⠁");

while  (s.find("b") != string::npos)
 s.replace(s.find("b"), 1, "⠃");

while  (s.find("c") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("c"), 1, "⠉");

 while (s.find("d") != string::npos)  
 s.replace(s.find("d"), 1, "⠙"); 

  while (s.find("e") != string::npos)
  s.replace(s.find("e"), 1, "⠑");

  while  (s.find("f") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("f"), 1, "⠋");

  while  (s.find("g") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("g"), 1, "⠛"); 

  while  (s.find("h") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("h"), 1, "⠓");       

   while  (s.find("i") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("i"), 1, "⠊"); 

   while  (s.find("j") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("j"), 1, "⠚"); 

  while  (s.find("k") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("k"), 1, "⠅"); 

  while  (s.find("l") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("l"), 1, "⠇"); 

   while  (s.find("m") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("m"), 1, "⠍"); 

   while  (s.find("n") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("n"), 1, "⠝"); 

   while  (s.find("o") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("o"), 1, "⠕"); 

   while  (s.find("p") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("p"), 1, "⠏"); 

  while  (s.find("q") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("q"), 1, "⠟"); 

  while  (s.find("r") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("r"), 1, "⠗"); 

  while  (s.find("s") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("s"), 1, "⠎"); 

 while  (s.find("t") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("t"), 1, "⠞"); 

 while  (s.find("u") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("u"), 1, "⠥"); 

 while  (s.find("v") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("v"), 1, "⠧"); 

 while  (s.find("w") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("w"), 1, "⠺"); 

 while  (s.find("x") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("x"), 1, "⠭"); 

while  (s.find("y") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("y"), 1, "⠽"); 

 while  (s.find("z") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("z"), 1, "⠵");

    //These are UPPER case letters. 
 while (s.find("A") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("A"), 1, "⠨⠁");

while  (s.find("B") != string::npos)
 s.replace(s.find("B"), 1, "⠨⠃");

while  (s.find("C") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("C"), 1, "⠨⠉");

 while (s.find("D") != string::npos)  
 s.replace(s.find("D"), 1, "⠨⠙"); 

 while (s.find("E") != string::npos)
s.replace(s.find("E"), 1, "⠨⠑");

while  (s.find("F") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("F"), 1, "⠨⠋");

while  (s.find("G") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("G"), 1, "⠨⠛"); 

 while  (s.find("H") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("H"), 1, "⠨⠓");       

 while  (s.find("I") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("I"), 1, "⠨⠊"); 

 while  (s.find("J") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("J"), 1, "⠨⠚"); 

 while  (s.find("K") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("K"), 1, "⠨⠅"); 

while  (s.find("L") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("L"), 1, "⠨⠇"); 

while  (s.find("M") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("M"), 1, "⠨⠍"); 

while  (s.find("N") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("N"), 1, "⠨⠝"); 

while  (s.find("O") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("O"), 1, "⠨⠕"); 

while  (s.find("P") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("P"), 1, "⠨⠏"); 

while  (s.find("Q") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("Q"), 1, "⠨⠟"); 

 while  (s.find("R") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("R"), 1, "⠨⠗"); 

 while  (s.find("S") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("S"), 1, "⠨⠎"); 

 while  (s.find("T") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("T"), 1, "⠨⠞"); 

 while  (s.find("U") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("U"), 1, "⠨⠥"); 

 while  (s.find("V") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("V"), 1, "⠨⠧"); 

while  (s.find("W") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("W"), 1, "⠨⠺"); 

while  (s.find("X") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("X"), 1, "⠨⠭"); 

while  (s.find("Y") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("Y"), 1, "⠨⠽"); 

 while  (s.find("Z") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("Z"), 1, "⠨⠵");

//These is some french letters.
    while  (s.find("é") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("é"), 1, "⠿");

    while  (s.find("à") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("à"), 1, "⠷");

    while  (s.find("â") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("â"), 1, "⠡");

    while  (s.find("ç") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("ç"), 1, "⠯");

    while  (s.find("è") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("è"), 1, "⠮");

    while  (s.find("ê") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("ê"), 1, "⠣");

    while  (s.find("ë") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("ë"), 1, "⠫");

    while  (s.find("î") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("î"), 1, "⠩");

    while  (s.find("ï") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("ï"), 1, "⠻");

    while  (s.find("ô") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("ô"), 1, "⠹");

    while  (s.find("œ") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("œ"), 1, "⠪");

    while  (s.find("ù") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("ù"), 1, "⠾");

    while  (s.find("û") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("û"), 1, "⠱");

    while  (s.find("ü") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("ü"), 1, "⠳");

 // These are numbers 0-9.   
     while (s.find("1") != string::npos)  
     s.replace(s.find("1"), 1, "⠼⠁");   

    while  (s.find("2") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("2"), 1, "⠼⠃");  

    while  (s.find("3") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("3"), 1, "⠼⠉");  

    while  (s.find("4") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("4"), 1, "⠼⠙");  

    while  (s.find("5") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("5"), 1, "⠼⠑");  

    while  (s.find("6") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("6"), 1, "⠼⠋");  

    while  (s.find("7") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("7"), 1, "⠼⠛");  

    while  (s.find("8") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("8"), 1, "⠼⠓");  

    while  (s.find("9") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("9"), 1, "⠼⠊");  

    while  (s.find("0") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("0"), 1, "⠼⠚");   


    // These are punctuation marks  
    while  (s.find(",") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find(","), 1, "⠂");  

    while  (s.find(";") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find(";"), 1, "⠆");  

    while  (s.find(":") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find(":"), 1, "⠒");  

    while  (s.find(".") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("."), 1, "⠲");  

    while  (s.find("?") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("?"), 1, "⠦");  

    while  (s.find("!") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("!"), 1, "⠖");  

    while  (s.find("‘") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("‘"), 1, "⠄");  

    while  (s.find("“") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("“"), 1, "⠄⠶");  

    while  (s.find("”") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("”"), 1, "⠘⠴");  

    while  (s.find("‘") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("‘"), 1, "⠄⠦");  

    while  (s.find("’") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("’"), 1, "⠄⠴");  

    while  (s.find("(") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("("), 1, "⠐⠣");  

    while  (s.find(")") != string::npos)       
    s.replace(s.find(")"), 1, "⠐⠜");  

    while  (s.find("/") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("/"), 1, "⠸⠌");  

    while  (s.find("–") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("–"), 1, "⠤");

    while (s.find("'") != string::npos)
    s.replace (s.find("'"), 1, "⠄");

    while (s.find("£") != string::npos)
    s.replace (s.find("£"), 1, "⠘⠇");

    while (s.find(".") != string::npos)
    s.replace (s.find("."), 1, "⠲");   

    while (s.find("*") != string::npos)
    s.replace (s.find("*"), 1, "⠔");  

    while (s.find("§") != string::npos)
    s.replace (s.find("§"), 1, "⠐⠏"); 

    while (s.find("&") != string::npos)
    s.replace (s.find("&"), 1, "⠐⠿"); 

    while (s.find("¥") != string::npos)
    s.replace (s.find("¥"), 1, "⠘⠽"); 

    while (s.find("€") != string::npos)
    s.replace (s.find("€"), 1, "⠘⠑");

    while (s.find("$") != string::npos)
    s.replace (s.find("$"), 1, "⠘⠎");

    while (s.find("©") != string::npos)
    s.replace (s.find("©"), 1, "⠐⠉");

    while (s.find("®") != string::npos)
    s.replace (s.find("®"), 1, "⠐⠗");

    while (s.find("™") != string::npos)
    s.replace (s.find("™"), 1, "⠐⠞");

    while (s.find("%") != string::npos)
    s.replace (s.find("%"), 1, "⠐⠬");

    while (s.find("‰") != string::npos)
    s.replace (s.find("‰"), 1, "⠐⠬⠬");

    while (s.find("‱") != string::npos)
    s.replace (s.find("‱"), 1, "⠐⠬⠬⠬");

    cout << s << endl;
}
```

ok so this is my code I have so far, and if you noticed this is completely out of hand and way too long. I'm not exactly the best at knowing functions in c++ but I really do feel like there's some easier way that would make this 1000000 times shorter or easier on the eye. Can someone explain or show me an easier way for this? Im quite new at this so please make it as simple as possible thank you!  To understand this long thing I want my program to read what is in a file and I want it to replace every character in it with what I tell it to be replaced it by so like I would want the letter a to be replaced by a dot etc... and then for it to be displayed as the dots.

Comment: Create a `const initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> reps = {{"a", "⠁"}, {"b", "⠃"}, ...};` ?

Comment: As @Jarod42 said, or simply an array `std::pair<std::string, std::sting> reps[] = {...};`.

Comment: BTW, it seems you can replace (unicode) character by character with a `map`.

Comment: Make a table of letters and Braille characters, then loop over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of repeatedly finding and replacing, it's much more efficient to walk the input string and look up the replacement for each character as you reach it.  We can can write the replacement function as a big `switch` or as a table:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

std::wstring to_braille(wchar_t c) noexcept
{
    static const std::map<wchar_t, std::wstring> table = {
        // lower case letters
        { L'a', L"⠁" }, { L'b', L"⠃" }, { L'c', L"⠉" }, { L'd', L"⠙" }, { L'e', L"⠑" },
        { L'f', L"⠋" }, { L'g', L"⠛" }, { L'h', L"⠓" }, { L'i', L"⠊" }, { L'j', L"⠚" },
        { L'k', L"⠅" }, { L'l', L"⠇" }, { L'm', L"⠍" }, { L'n', L"⠝" }, { L'o', L"⠕" },
        { L'p', L"⠏" }, { L'q', L"⠟" }, { L'r', L"⠗" }, { L's', L"⠎" }, { L't', L"⠞" },
        { L'u', L"⠥" }, { L'v', L"⠧" }, { L'w', L"⠺" }, { L'x', L"⠭" }, { L'y', L"⠽" },
        { L'z', L"⠵" },
        // UPPER case letters
        { L'A', L"⠨⠁" }, { L'B', L"⠨⠃" }, { L'C', L"⠨⠉" }, { L'D', L"⠨⠙" }, { L'E', L"⠨⠑" },
        { L'F', L"⠨⠋" }, { L'G', L"⠨⠛" }, { L'H', L"⠨⠓" }, { L'I', L"⠨⠊" }, { L'J', L"⠨⠚" },
        { L'K', L"⠨⠅" }, { L'L', L"⠨⠇" }, { L'M', L"⠨⠍" }, { L'N', L"⠨⠝" }, { L'O', L"⠨⠕" },
        { L'P', L"⠨⠏" }, { L'Q', L"⠨⠟" }, { L'R', L"⠨⠗" }, { L'S', L"⠨⠎" }, { L'T', L"⠨⠞" },
        { L'U', L"⠨⠥" }, { L'V', L"⠨⠧" }, { L'W', L"⠨⠺" }, { L'X', L"⠨⠭" }, { L'Y', L"⠨⠽" },
        { L'Z', L"⠨⠵" },
        // accented letters
        { L'é', L"⠿" }, { L'à', L"⠷" }, { L'â', L"⠡" }, { L'ç', L"⠯" }, { L'è', L"⠮" },
        { L'ê', L"⠣" }, { L'ë', L"⠫" }, { L'î', L"⠩" }, { L'ï', L"⠻" }, { L'ô', L"⠹" },
        { L'œ', L"⠪" }, { L'ù', L"⠾" }, { L'û', L"⠱" }, { L'ü', L"⠳" },
        // digits
        { L'1', L"⠼⠁" }, { L'2', L"⠼⠃" }, { L'3', L"⠼⠉" }, { L'4', L"⠼⠙" }, { L'5', L"⠼⠑" },
        { L'6', L"⠼⠋" }, { L'7', L"⠼⠛" }, { L'8', L"⠼⠓" }, { L'9', L"⠼⠊" }, { L'0', L"⠼⠚" },
        // punctuation
        { L',', L"⠂" }, { L';', L"⠆" }, { L':', L"⠒" }, { L'.', L"⠲" }, { L'?', L"⠦" },
        { L'!', L"⠖" }, { L'‘', L"⠄" }, { L'“', L"⠄⠶" }, { L'”', L"⠘⠴" }, { L'‘', L"⠄⠦" },
        { L'’', L"⠄⠴" }, { L'(', L"⠐⠣" }, { L')', L"⠐⠜" }, { L'/', L"⠸⠌" }, { L'–', L"⠤" },
        { L'\'', L"⠄" }, { L'£', L"⠘⠇" }, { L'.', L"⠲" }, { L'*', L"⠔" }, { L'§', L"⠐⠏" },
        { L'&', L"⠐⠿" }, { L'¥', L"⠘⠽" }, { L'€', L"⠘⠑" }, { L'$', L"⠘⠎" }, { L'©', L"⠐⠉" },
        { L'®', L"⠐⠗" }, { L'™', L"⠐⠞" }, { L'%', L"⠐⠬" }, { L'‰', L"⠐⠬⠬" }, { L'‱', L"⠐⠬⠬⠬" },
    };

    auto const it = table.find(c);
    if (it == table.end())
        return std::wstring{} + c; // fallback - use character unchanged
    else
        return it->second;
}
```

Given this, it's pretty easy to convert each character in turn:

```
std::wstring to_braille(const std::wstring& s)
{
    std::wstring braille;
    braille.reserve(s.size());  // output is at least as big as input

    for (wchar_t c: s)
        braille += to_braille(c);

    return braille;
}
```

Demo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
int main()
{
    std::locale::global(std::locale{""});
    std::wcout << to_braille(L"Hello World!");
}
```

```
⠨⠓⠑⠇⠇⠕ ⠨⠺⠕⠗⠇⠙⠖
```

Comment: You might want to add uppercase accented letters, too - I just transformed your function directly.

Comment: yes i shall try, im just trying to find easier ways and slowly improve it

Comment: instead of displaying the characters of whatever is inside the main function (Hello world for this instance) how can I make it so it is a cin value? Like if I write the words Hello it will then do it?

Comment: @Zachary, just call the function in a loop, just like you were doing in the question code - e.g. `std::wstring s; while (std::getline(std::wcin, s)) { std::wcout << to_braille(s) << std::endl; }`.  That's the real benefit of using functions effectively!

Comment: Note: `sizeof (wchat_t)` can be 1, even with size >2, unicode might be encoded into ore than one wchar_t.

Comment: Yes.  In hindsight, I should have recommended working with BMP codepoints as `std::u16string`, or (if necessary) full Unicode characters as `std::u32string`.  It's pretty trivial to take the above logic and convert, though.

Comment: Wow, I really need to settle down and learn about this... It's so fascinating. I'm already going to computer science at University because I'm so intrigued by this... Does anyone have suggestions for books/YouTube tutorials that help? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I can expand on my comment to your earlier question.

First, let's look at what your current code does inside the outer loop. So you're in the position where you have a string called `s` and you want to translate each character to another form (specifically, its braille form, but that detail does not impact the logic). In order to do this, you (via `find()`) step through each character of the string until you find an `'a'`. If you find one, you then (calling `find()` again) step through each character of the string until you find an `'a'` and replace that character. Then you repeat this: starting again at the beginning of the string, you step through each character until you find an `'a'`. And so on.

*For example, given the string `"gala"`, find the first `'a'` by looking at `'g'` then `'a'`. OK, there is a replacement to be made. So find the first `'a'` by looking at `'g'` then `'a'` and replace that, giving you `"g⠁la"`. Now find the next `'a'` by looking at `'g'`, `'⠁'`, `'l'`, then `'a'`. OK, there is a replacement to be made. So find the next `'a'` by looking at `'g'`, `'⠁'`, `'l'`, then `'a'` and replace that, giving you `"g⠁l⠁"`. Now find the next `'a'` by looking at `'g'`, `'⠁'`, `'l'`, then `'⠁'`. Oh we're done. Whew. Only had to look at **16** of the 4 characters!*

Once you are done replacing `'a'`, you repeat this process for each letter in the alphabet, and then some. If you gave these instructions to a human,  they'd at best complain about being given busy work.

---

How would you do this task if you had to do it by hand? Would you look for a's and replace them, or would you go character-by-character and replace each as you encounter it? Most people would do the latter. So let's try telling the computer to use this approach.

Start by implementing "character by character". There are different ways to do this. For instructive purposes, I'll go with `for ( auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it )`. This causes the variable `it` to step through the string, from beginning to end, pointing to each character in turn with each iteration of the loop. The next task is to replace each character. How to do this? It's not trivial, so let's push that off to another function, call it `to_braille`. And since some replacements are more than one character, it's probably more convenient to build a new string. With these decisions, your mess of loops becomes the following.

```
while (getline(input, s)) {
    std::wstring braille;

    for ( auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it )
        braille.append(to_braille(*it));

    wcout << braille << endl;
}
```

Don't get too excited. There is still a monster function to write; all this has done is get rid of unnecessary looping. Still, the monster function is fairly straight-forward. The comments have some suggestions for how to do this, but as a starting point, you could just do a monster `switch`. (Given how long this function would be, I'd be inclined to give it its own source file so you don't have to look at it often.)

```
std::wstring to_braille(char c)
{
    switch ( c )
    {
        case 'a': return L"⠁";
        case 'b': return L"⠃";
        case 'c': return L"⠉";
        // And so on. You can write the rest.
    }
    // Unknown characters are not changed.
    return std::wstring(1, c);
}
```

The main point of all this is to **think about what you want to do; don't choose tools simply because they could be used.** Also, divide and conquer.

*Note:* Based on comments, I've switched the string being built from `string` to `wstring`. I did not change the string being read from the file, though. You may need to go over your program to see where wide characters are required.

Comment: Much better explanation than my answer.  +1

Comment: But do note that your `to_braille` needs to return a `std::wstring` - some of the replacements are two or three characters long.

Comment: @TobySpeight Ah, so they are. Tough to see that in the mess of loops. I'll fix that up, but why `wstring` instead of `string`? Since types were not mentioned in this question, I'd be inclined to go with the types from the [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50901050/header-file-in-c-wont-work-in-netbbeans-ide-8-2-gives-errors).

Comment: On my platform, the Braille characters are outside the range of plain `char`, so `std::wstring` is more appropriate.  Perhaps that's different where you are?

Comment: @TobySpeight OK, `wstring` it is. Maybe this will head off the next question about why the code is not working. :)

Comment: Don't worry too much - my answer includes a tested working example, so it complements yours (we were obviously answering at the same time).

Comment: BTW, when I had `std::wstring(1, c)` like that, the output had embedded NUL characters, and I had to change it to `std::wstring{} + c`.  I don't understand why the former didn't work (and I even tried an explicit cast to `wchar_t`).  Can anybody explain why?  And more importantly, show the Right Way to widen `char` to `std::wstring`?

Comment: Yes it's true I did get very excited at first I was just testing with whole words but then I got out of hand. I did think of the for loop with a .size however I am not too familiar. Obviously as you can see from this I am not very experience at programming. I have a more hyperactive reaction as in I have an idea and I start it right away and then I make it better (had several medical problems 10 months ago and got brain damage from dying for a little too long so I have a shit memory at this point So the moment I have an idea I write the program down right away) Thank you tho! helped me alot